# Read any text file in Android and convert contents to UTF-8?

Tags: android, character-encoding, special-characters, android-3.0-honeycomb, character

Is it possible to read a text file in Android and convert its content to UTF-8, so all the usual special characters are shown correctly? I am especially talking about some European characters, like Æ, Ø, Å, Ö, and Ä.

Thanks a lot.

**Solution:**
I eventually used a mix of evilone's suggestion and some code that replaces the wrong characters with the correct ones. Not perfect, but it works.

Comment: Hi Michell, I have just same task now. What was your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very robust example:

```
String filePath = "/sdcard/utf8_file.txt";
String UTF8 = "utf8";
int BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath), UTF8),BUFFER_SIZE);
```

**EDIT:**

[How to auto-detect a file’s encoding](http://cyberpython.wordpress.com/2010/04/08/java-how-to-auto-detect-a-files-encoding/)

Comment: Yeah, I tried this with a number of files, but it didn't seem to work out completely. I'm building a subtitle reader, and some of the subtitle contents are not read properly using this.

Comment: Are you saving your .txt file with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: No, that's the thing. I can't be sure which encoding is used, but I need to make sure that I am able to display the contents of the file the way it was meant to be shown. So my app needs to be able to read UTF-8, ANSI, etc.

Comment: Only supporting files in UTF-8 renders the application more or less useless... :-(

Comment: The problem is that there isn't anything in the file that says what
encoding it is using. You can look at some byte patterns to try to
determine whether it's UTF-8, ANSI, or whatever but there's no perfect
rule for it.

Comment: Edited my answer. Added link to EncoderTester class. You can try it, but I'm not tested it and can not tell if this is working or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is automatic detection of charset. This is no trivial task. You should google around for existing solutions, like [jChardet](http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

I eventually used a mix of evilone's suggestion and some code that replaces the wrong characters with the correct ones. Not perfect, but it works.